# Extracting multiple matrix from a single matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix(type double) similar to the following example:

```
X = [ 23 3 5 1; 
      21 45 8 1; 
      65 56 7 1; 
      71 42 4 2; 
      45 91 5 2; 
      34  6 1 3; 
      87 37 8 3;  
      23 3 5  3]
```

Based on the element of the fourth column I want to get 3 matrix from the above matrix like the following example;

```
    A=[ 23 3 5 1;         
        21 45 8 1; 
        65 56 7 1; ]

    B =[ 71 42 4 2; 
         45 91 5 2; ]

  C =[ 34  6 1 3; 
       87 37 8 3;  
       23 3 5  3;]
```

Basically I want to seprate all the 1s,2s and 3s of the fourth column into another matrix. How can I do it in the Matlab!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A = X(:,X(:,4)==1);
B = X(:,X(:,4)==2);
C = X(:,X(:,4)==3);
```